# Matlab Substring as function call?

Tags: string, matlab, substring

I am trying to figure out this substring feature and whether there exists a function call for it or not. As far as I can find, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16126847/how-do-i-get-substring-to-work-in-matlab) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366333/extract-substring-from-the-last-position-in-matlab) along with various other places, there simply is no related function for this since strings are char arrays, and so they settled for only implementing the indexing feature.

MWE:

```
fileID = fopen('tryMe.env');
outDate = fgetl(fileID);
```

Where the file `'tryMe.env'` only consists of 1 line like so:

```
2014/9/4
```

My wanted result is:

```
outDate = 
    '14/9/4'
```

I am trying to find a clean, smooth one liner to go with the variable definition of `outDate`, something along the lines of `outDate = fgetl(fileID)(3:end);`, and not several lines of code.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This is possible, but I have to ask: Why can't you live with two lines?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627107/how-can-i-index-a-matlab-array-returned-by-a-function-without-first-assigning-it

Comment: I guess I am used to too much C, and simply cherish minimal but functional and readable code. I guess with the answer posted in Cheery's link, two lines solution is a bit more handsome. Thank you

Comment: try `outDate = datestr( datenum ( fgetl( fopen('tryMe.txt') ) ) , 'yy/mm/dd')` for a one liner ... but you still will have to close the file after, and i'm not sure about 'readability' on some one liners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific example you gave, seems like

```
outDate=textscan(fileID, '%*2c%infc')
```

would do what you want ( skip 2 characters, then read until end of line).

If you are trying to read a date, which you will later want to manipulate as a date, like comparing, differencing, etc, you could also use `datenum` on your `fgetl` line. Or, if you want a normalized date string, For instance

```
outDate=datestr(datenum(fgetl(fileID)),'yy/mm/dd')
```

would produce the string '14/09/04'

Comment: Yes thank you, it would seem that your first example is what I was looking for since I need to handle the input as nothing but strings